# Graphql-config does not recognize Apollo Graphql @client directive

Tags: intellij-idea, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-tag

I'm using Apollo Client with React, [graphql-tag](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag) loaded with Webpack, and [graphql-config](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-config) to maintain the schema on the client.

There is a file `./myclient/src/features/stats/graphql/getStart.graphql`

```
query GetStart {
    start @client
}
```

where `start` and `@client` don't validate with the IDE graphql plugin because they are not included in the auto generated schema.

The `./myclient/.graphqlconfig` file

```
{
    "projects": {
    "client": {
      "schemaPath": "schema.graphql",
      "extensions": {
        "endpoints": {
          "dev": "http://localhost:3000/graphql"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Webpack is configured to load the graphql schema on the client with

```
{
  test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: 'graphql-tag/loader',
},
```

It will load the server schema correctly. But, how do I configure it to validate or ignore the `start @client` which is causing `Unknown field "start" on object "Query"` and `Unknown directive "@client"` errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to define client side schema for Apollo client, [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state/#client-side-schema). I created a file `./src/apollo/graphql/typeDefs.graphql` that contained the type definitions.

```
directive @client on FIELD

type RestParams {
    limit: Int
    page: Int
}

extend type Query {
    restParams: RestParams
}
```

I imported the `typeDefs.graphql` into the `client.js` file and added `typeDefs` to the `ApolloClient` constructor options.

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

import TYPE_DEFS from './graphql/typeDefs.graphql';
import createHttpLink from './links/httpLink';
import createErrorLink from './links/errorLink';
import createAuthLink from './links/authLink';

const errorLink = createErrorLink();
const httpLink = createHttpLink();
const authLink = createAuthLink();

const cache = new InMemoryCache({});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    authLink,
    errorLink,
    httpLink,
  ]),
  // resolves,
  typeDefs: TYPE_DEFS,
  connectToDevTools: true,
});

export default client;
```

Not are the type definitions discoverable by the IDE but they also are discoverable by the Apollo Chrome inspector plugin.